# Issue when creating a catkin workspace - workspace = home directory

Tags: kineticjs, catkin

first time I have this issue and I do not understand why... When I want to create a catkin workspace, I create a new directory and do `catkin_make` or `catkin init` and actually the workspace is always my home directory not the new workspace I have created. And thus a `build` and `devel` directories are created on my home directory as well. Do you know what I am missing here? Thank you very much for your help

```
emeric@emeric-desktop:~$ cd catkin_planning_ws/
emeric@emeric-desktop:~/catkin_planning_ws$ ls
src
emeric@emeric-desktop:~/catkin_planning_ws$ catkin init
Catkin workspace `/home/emeric` is already initialized. No action taken.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /home/emeric/catkin_wsp/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/emeric
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source Space:       [exists] /home/emeric/src
Log Space:         [missing] /home/emeric/logs
Build Space:       [missing] /home/emeric/build
Devel Space:       [missing] /home/emeric/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/emeric/install
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       DCMAKE_BUILT_TYPE=Release
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the exactly the same problem and here is the solution：

```
1. cd  #go to home dir
2. ls -la | grep catkin  #cheak if there is a dir named *.catkin_tools*, that's the problem!!!
3. rm -r .catkin_tools
```

Done!
Hope this works for your case too.